# Error al instalar create-react-app globalmente

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

Instalo globalmente create-react-app con `npm i -g create-react-app`. Parece que se ha instalado correctamente, pero cuando lo pruebo con `create-react-app` me tira un error de que no se reconoce como comando interno o externo. Desinstalarlo y volver a instalarlo no funciona, ya he probado.

[image: El error que me tira la consola:]

Comment: Es posible que la ruta donde están las librerías de npm no estén en tu  `PATH`. ¿Qué te dice la consola al ejecutar `path`? ¿Qué te aparece con `npm prefix -g`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create-react-app` no es un paquete. La verdadera forma es:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Utilizando npx.

> En la primera línea npx no es un error de escritura: Es una herramienta de ejecución de paquetes que viene con npm 5.2+.

Ejemplo de facebook:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

Más información [aquí.](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)

Answer (score 0):

-Primero instalamos la version mas catual de `npm`

`npm install -g npm@latests`

-Limpiamos el cache para que no se nos instale una version antigua

`npm cache clear --force`

- instalamos create-react-app

`npm install -g create-react-app`

-creamos una nueva app
`npx create-react-app reactapp`